# JSON Schema Semantic Annotation

Tags: json, jsonschema

In the following link sawsdl:modelReference in XML Schema is used for semantic annotation in order to map between different schemas: [Link](https://tc.ifac-control.org/5/3/events/ei2n2010-folder/ei2n2010-presentations-reports-and-conclusions/EI2N%202010%20Kopke%20et%20al.pdf)

I want to create semantic annotations for JSON Schema for the same purpose. Is there something like sawsdl for JSON?

If not, can I use the id property? As far as I know id property can be used relative (“$id” : “billing/address”) or absolute (“$id”: “#billingAddress”).

In my case the id would look like this example:
“$id” : “order/hasBillingAddress/Address”

Or is it possible to create a custom property for example 
“SemanticAnnotation” : “order/hasBillingAddress/Address”?

I have read the specification and as far as I can tell, neither of those approaches seem to be contradicted by the specification. I have also checked both options with a JSON Schema validator which also found no problems.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema does not yet directly support semantic annotations, although there is [an issue open for the idea](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/309).  At the moment, no one has time to work on a proposal, but it is something that I think is worth exploring, particularly in conjunction with JSON-LD.  Please feel free to add your use cases to the issue.

The `$id` property is for assigning a URI to a schema so that it can be referenced from elsewhere.  The "#billingAddress" form is declaring a fragment URI that is local to that schema file (The "#" is the URI fragment syntax marker, and is not specific to JSON Schema).

The "billing/address" form is declaring a URI with a relative path.  This is usually only done when packing multiple logical schemas into a single file, so that references targeting the original file name and path remain valid.  Setting a non-fragment `$id` changes hour `$ref` references are resolved, which is probably not what you want.

Since JSON Schema validators ignore keywords they do not understand, the simplest thing for you to do may be to just define your own extension keywords for this.  They will not be recognized by other applications, so I guess it depends on your audience.  Several validator programs make it easy to hook in support for custom keywords.